# Updating only one field in the payload in dataweave 2.0 without touching other fields

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Considering a payload...

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "age": 17,
  "gender": "Male"
}
```

I want to change the age based upon a condition. I am able to do the following (the payload may have more key-value pairs which we are not interested into)

```
output application/java
---
payload ++ {age: (if(payload.age > 18) payload.age else 18}
```

But as you can see the output format is java. To convert it into JSON, I need to add another Transform Message for it, which does not look like a good coding practice and also I cannot afford the cost of using an extra Transform Message. If I do

```
output application/json
---
payload ++ {age: (if(payload.age > 18) payload.age else 18}
```

The output I get is

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "age": 17,
  "gender": "Male",
  "age": 18
}
```

Is there any other way of doing this?

**PART 2**
Having difficulty with payload with nested objects.

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "data": {
    "personalData": {
      "age": 17,
      "gender": "Male"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Update still works with nested objects - read the docs. There are many examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old way:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    (payload - "age"),
    age: if (payload.age > 18) payload.age else 18
}
```

New way with the [update](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-values-functions-update) function.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
output application/json
---
payload update "age" with (if (payload.age > 18) payload.age else 18)
```

Update for part 2. Per the docs you can specify a path. Read the docs.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
output application/json
---
payload update ["data", "personalData", "age"] with (if (payload.data.personalData.age > 18) payload.data.personalData.age else 18)
```

I'm a bit confused; why would you need to do multiple transforms with that as your input? Just set your transform with `output application/json`. Don't use object concatenation to change a value like this either.

Comment: Thanks. I kinda missed the 'update' keyword. Helped alot.

Comment: Hi, Micheal can you guide me for the PART-2 of the question, for the same key.

Comment: @SatyamPisal - Please accept the answer if you're satisfied with it.